# How to start many ElasticSearch nodes in one Machine

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to start each node with one machine and one cluser (on localhost only - testing purpose) with the following command:

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
 -Des.node.data=false 
 -Des.node.master=true 
 -Des.node.name=NoData --default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch/
```

However, I can't start even one node becouse  I keep getting this error even when starting the first node:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: don't run
> elasticsearch as root.    at
> org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:93)
>   at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:144)
>   at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)   at
> org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
> Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

How to start many ES nodes on one machine?

(ES is installed form official deb repo of ES)

EDIT
I wanted to run it like below

```
$ bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.1.yml
$ bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.2.yml
$ bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.testNoData.yml
```

BUT TWO PROBLEMS

1. It does NOT work becouse of the above.
2. Still not sure **what should be within those 3 yml files?**

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I spent some time trying find the same answer and only came upon these old threads that basically say "don't do that". I finally happened upon a solution that I've been running for over 6 months without issue. You basically have to leverage variables in the config file. Check out the full instructions [at this link](https://eitr.tech/blog/2019/01/17/multiple-es-nodes-single-server.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start many nodes for testing purposes, I strongly recommend to use the [`esvm` tool](https://github.com/simianhacker/esvm).

That tool is specifically designed for rapidly testing your code against different ES versions running on one or many nodes. For instance, you can start a 5-node cluster (2 master + 3 data) very easily using [this configuration file](https://github.com/simianhacker/esvm/blob/master/examples/five_nodes.md):

```
{
  "clusters": {
    "2m3d": {
      "plugins": ["mobz/elasticsearch-head"],
      "nodes": [
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "master-1", "data": false, "master": true }
        },
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "master-2", "data": false, "master": true }
        },
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "data-1", "data": true, "master": false }
        },
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "data-2", "data": true, "master": false }
        },
        {
          "cluster": { "name": "2m3d" },
          "node": { "name": "data-3", "data": true, "master": false }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above cluster can be launched very simply by running

```
> esvm 2m3d
```

Comment: I have installed `esvm` however, after the `esvm 2m3d` it starts to download `Elasticsearc-2.3.5` wich I have already installed at the machine as a service. Can I force `esvm` to use the already installed `2.3.5` version or do i have to let `esvm` to download and install its own ES?

Comment: esvm uses its own ES instances, you can let it download and install ES, your service install won't be overridden.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have accepted and up voted your post.

Comment: @Val hey ! When I try to do what u suggested 'esvm 2m3d' it starts running two nodes but than i get the error      "failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/home/nad/.esvm/5.4.1/data/2m3d]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?"   any Idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to start more than one ES node on your server you will have to set different configuration for each node (different port, different data folder and so on). This will probably involve some hard work and is not recommended since different ES nodes will probably still conflict and fail.
2. The error clearly says you should not run Elasticsearch as root, and you are running it with sudo - which makes it run as root.
   Try running ES by launching the its service, by using the command - `sudo service elasticsearch start`. This will start the ES daemon with proper configuration.

Comment: ad 1. ok , can you be a little bit more specyfic on how exactly this should be done? I need namy nodes in my dev testing. I dont have 5 machines just to run 5 nodes tests.

Comment: ad 2. I know that u can run a service that way. But querstion is about many nodes not one node as this command starts by default.

Comment: Like I said - ES was not built to share machines with other ES processes. What you can try to do is launch an ES container that simulate a separate machine. If you'll configure your containers in a smart way you might be able to launch 5 of them on the same machine, but this also sounds very time-consuming to me.